# PL/SQL create view base on dynamic table name

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-tables

I'm trying to create a view that access all the tables starting with the same name, they have the exactly same structure, and in time there will be more.

Table Names:

```
TEMP_ENTITIES_1000
TEMP_ENTITIES_1001
TEMP_ENTITIES_1002
```

and in the future there will be

```
TEMP_ENTITIES_1003
TEMP_ENTITIES_1004
```

and so on...

What I need is to use list of tables from the following script and then use the result the list of object name result to access in a view.

```
select object_name
from user_objects 
where object_type  = 'TABLE'
and object_name like upper('temp_entities_%');

create view entities_join as
select * from (object_name)
```

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Those table names, and the way you describe them and state that in the future there will be more, _VERY STRONGLY_ suggests a fatally flawed design.  Why do you have multiple tables of the same design?  Why isn't all this data in a single table, perhaps with an additional column to indicate whatever it was you are separating them on?  Perhaps that extra column could be used as a partitioning key in a single partitioned table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes, using dynamic SQL.

However, from what you described, it looks that data model you use is **wrong**. You should have only one table with *identifier* that makes the difference (those 1000, 1001, ... values).

Then you wouldn't need a view at all, and do everything with that single table. I suggest you consider doing so.

---

Here's an example of what you might do (the way you asked):

Several sample tables:

```
SQL> select * from temp_entities_1000;

        ID NAME
---------- ------
      1000 Little

SQL> select * from temp_entities_1001;

        ID NAME
---------- ----
      1001 Foot

SQL> select * from temp_entities_1002;

        ID NAME
---------- -----
      1002 Scott
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_str  VARCHAR2 (2000);
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR cur_r IN (SELECT object_name
  5                     FROM user_objects
  6                    WHERE     object_type = 'TABLE'
  7                          AND object_name LIKE 'TEMP_ENTITIES%')
  8     LOOP
  9        l_str :=
 10           l_str || ' select * from ' || cur_r.object_name || ' union all ';
 11     END LOOP;
 12
 13     l_str :=
 14           'create or replace view entities_join as '
 15        || RTRIM (l_str, ' union all');
 16
 17     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
 18  END;
 19  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from entities_join;

        ID NAME
---------- ------
      1000 Little
      1001 Foot
      1002 Scott

SQL>
```

You'd have to run that procedure every time new table is created so that it is included into the view.

Answer (score 2):

In modern versions of Oracle you may use [SQL table macros](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nfcon/details-sql-macros-282451004.html) without scheduled anything. It will build dynamic query on-the-fly and may be used as a plain view.

Below is the example:

```
SQL> insert all 
  2    when mod(rownum, 5) = 0 then into TEMP_ENTITIES_1000 values (l, dt, val) 
  3    when mod(rownum, 5) = 1 then into TEMP_ENTITIES_1001 values (l, dt, val) 
  4    when mod(rownum, 5) = 2 then into TEMP_ENTITIES_1002 values (l, dt, val) 
  5    when mod(rownum, 5) = 3 then into TEMP_ENTITIES_1003 values (l, dt, val) 
  6    when mod(rownum, 5) = 4 then into TEMP_ENTITIES_1004 values (l, dt, val) 
  7  
  8  select 
  9    level as l, 
 10    sysdate + level as dt, 
 11    level as val 
 12  from dual 
 13  connect by level < 10;

9 rows inserted.

SQL> 
SQL> create or replace function f_temp_entities_union 
  2  /*Create a macro*/
  3  return varchar2 SQL_MACRO
  4  is 
  5    v_union varchar2(4000); 
  6  begin 
  7    select listagg('select ''' || table_name || ''' as src, a.* from ' || table_name || ' a ', chr(10) || 'union all' || chr(10)) 
  8      into v_union 
  9    from all_tables 
 10    where table_name like 'TEMP_ENTITIES%' 
 11      and owner = sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') 
 12    ; 
 13  
 14    return v_union; 
 15  end;
 16  /

Function F_TEMP_ENTITIES_UNION compiled

SQL> 
SQL> select * 
  2  from f_temp_entities_union();
TEMP_ENTITIES_1000          5 20.09.21          5
TEMP_ENTITIES_1001          1 16.09.21          1
TEMP_ENTITIES_1001          6 21.09.21          6
TEMP_ENTITIES_1002          2 17.09.21          2
TEMP_ENTITIES_1002          7 22.09.21          7
TEMP_ENTITIES_1003          3 18.09.21          3
TEMP_ENTITIES_1003          8 23.09.21          8
TEMP_ENTITIES_1004          4 19.09.21          4
TEMP_ENTITIES_1004          9 24.09.21          9

9 rows selected. 

SQL> 
SQL> /*Add new table*/
SQL> create table TEMP_ENTITIES_1005 as select * from TEMP_ENTITIES_1001 where 1 = 0;

Table TEMP_ENTITIES_1005 created.

SQL> insert into TEMP_ENTITIES_1005
  2  select 1000 + rownum, sysdate + rownum, rownum - 100 from TEMP_ENTITIES_1000;

1 row inserted.

SQL> 
SQL> /*Check that new data is here*/
SQL> select *
  2  from v_demo;
TEMP_ENTITIES_1000          5 20.09.21          5
TEMP_ENTITIES_1001          1 16.09.21          1
TEMP_ENTITIES_1001          6 21.09.21          6
TEMP_ENTITIES_1002          2 17.09.21          2
TEMP_ENTITIES_1002          7 22.09.21          7
TEMP_ENTITIES_1003          3 18.09.21          3
TEMP_ENTITIES_1003          8 23.09.21          8
TEMP_ENTITIES_1004          4 19.09.21          4
TEMP_ENTITIES_1004          9 24.09.21          9
TEMP_ENTITIES_1005       1001 16.09.21        -99

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: Nice confrontation of the *old* and *new* world in two answers. The accepted answer should be definitively this *new perspective macro* approach